# Url not woking in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

My Question is in two fold, both revolving round NoReverseMatch error. **First Question**: I keep getting NoReverseMatch error each time i call my url(**{% url 'dashboard' client.pk %}**) in other pages that uses a different view(eg **DashboardPilot**: *kindly check the url*) but when i use it in **dashboard.html** it works fine.

### Views.py

```
class Dashboard(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = ClientProfile
    template_name ='accounts/dashboard.html'
    context_object_name= 'client'
    login_url= 'login'
    fields = '__all__'
    def test_func(self):
            return self.request.user.role == 'client'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('accounts/dashboard/client/<int:pk>', Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('accounts/dashboard/pilot/<int:pk>', DashboardPilot.as_view(), name='pilot_dashboard'),
    path('jobs', JobPage.as_view(), name='job_page'),
    path('job/<int:pk>/details', JobDetails.as_view(), name='job_details'),
    path('accounts/edit/job/<int:pk>', EditJob.as_view(), name='job_edit'),
]

**models.py**

 class ClientProfile(models.Model):
   username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
   client_firstname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   client_lastname=models.CharField(max_length =150)
   role =models.CharField(max_length =150)
   client_phone_no=models.CharField(max_length =150)
   client_email=models.EmailField(max_length=150)
```

Second Questions:
I have a view which redirect to a dashboard(uses pk) after signing but i keep getting a reverse error each time it tries to redirect to dashboard.

**views.py**

```
def signin (request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
        if user.role == 'client':
            return redirect ('dashboard')
        else:
            return redirect ('pilot_dashboard')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect ('login')

  else:
    return render (request, 'accounts/signin.html')
```

### **urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns =[
    path('accounts/dashboard/client/<int:pk>', Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('accounts/dashboard/pilot/<int:pk>', DashboardPilot.as_view(), name='pilot_dashboard'),
    path('jobs', JobPage.as_view(), name='job_page'),
    path('job/<int:pk>/details', JobDetails.as_view(), name='job_details'),
    path('accounts/edit/job/<int:pk>', EditJob.as_view(), name='job_edit'),
]
```

I i have tried using **return redirect(reverse('dashboard', args=[str(self.id)]))** but i keep getting self not defined. **I will be immensely grateful for any help rendered**.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, please make sure that `client` object is present in the template. Most probably, your template context does not have the object `client` which is why url is not resolved. You can test this by including `{{ client }}` in the templates that are giving you the error.
Basically you need to pass the correct object inside the `url` template tag.

You can add the `client` object in the context if your view does not have the `ClientProfile` in your template's context.

For the second problem, call the `reverse` with the `kwargs` keyword. Also, you are not passing the correct value to resolve the url.

Use:

`return redirect(reverse('dashboard', kwargs={"pk": user.clientprofile.id}))`

Comment: Thanks @Aman Garg for your reply. I tried specifying client object but i still got same error in my update view and create view pages. Also i tried using ** return redirect(reverse('dashboard', kwargs={"pk": user.clientprofile.id})) ** but i still got the reverse error.

Comment: can you check this by hard coding a pk in the url? is that working? try on an existing pk. `redirect(reverse('dashboard', kwargs=1))`